# Why rails isn't displaying a web page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, html

Each time I launch a rails application, the server displays an error message. For instance (this is from the command line):

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-10 00:12:31 -0600
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2054ms

ActionView::Template::Error (TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
(in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)):
3: <head>
4:   <title>AlphaBlog</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
9: <body>
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___602047428_59662224'


Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.0ms)
Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (64.8ms)
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The first way to solve.** Add to file `application.js` this line:

```
//= require turbolinks
```

**The second method of solving.**  In `Gemfile` set version `1.8.0` for `gem 'coffee-script-source'` :

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the javascript_include_tag (line indicated as broken) and see if the page loads.  If the page does load, then it maybe something wrong with the assets files regarding javascript.